# How to get View display label for field?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to enable grouping for the Views Datasource module. I'm looping through the `$rows` array, which is where output is stored by the module before it's formatted into JSON. Problem is, the grouping field is stored in `$options` as its machine name, but `$rows` uses the user-defined label for field names. Basically, I just need a function to take the machine name for a field and return the display-set label for it.

I already tried [field_views_field_label](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!field.views.inc/function/field_views_field_label/7), but it returns an array of the labels for fields defined in the **content type**, where I need the label defined in the **view display**.

```
$group = $options["grouping"][0]["field"];
// Get grouping field as defined by the field options in the view display
$root = $options["root_object"];
$top_child = $options["top_child_object"];
if ($group) {
  $grouped = array();
    foreach ($rows[$root] as $key => $array) { // Values are numeric
      // Grab the grouping field value from inside the 3rd-level array.
      // Creating a label for grouping field will break everything
      $groupnode = $array[$top_child][$group];
      foreach ($array[$top_child] as $prop => $value) {
        if ($prop != $group) { // Ignore grouped field
          $grouped[$root][$groupnode][$prop][$key] = $value;
        }
      }
    }
  $rows = $grouped;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally learned of the [Search Krumo](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_krumo) module, which let me search for the variable I was looking for. It was `$view->query->pager->display->handler->handlers['field'][$group]->options['label']`, where `$group` is the machine name of the grouped field. No function was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to take a look at [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54883/what-hook-can-i-use-to-modify-views-datasource-json-output) which provides lots of information on how to change the output produced by Views Datasource. This should give you a starter.