# Customize labels of view

Tags: 7, views

I created a template to customize the image field of my view, but I see no change to its output. Can you help me ? thank you

I have to clear the cache of my website.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I already asked this question but I can no longer enter my account

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: yes I have to clear the cache. When you view is that it works for you?

Comment: @Mathieu since you're using the Views Datasource, that method will not work. You have to create a custom module. Similary to [What hook can I use to modify Views Datasource JSON output?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54883/what-hook-can-i-use-to-modify-views-datasource-json-output) except in your case its XML instead.

Comment: @No Sssweat thank you for your answer, but I can not do that. I have the following modules installed on drupal 7 "PHP filter", "Views Data Export" and "XML Views, Views XHTML, RDF Views, Views JSON." I must get this https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=fr with the alt tag and more.

Comment: I have a preference for the module "Views data export" I already use for other views.

Comment: @Mathieu ah, I will look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @Mathieu doesn't look like you're using "Views data export" for this. On your screenshot for Format it says _"xml data document"_ which is from the Views XML module. Views XML is part of the Views DataSource module.

Comment: @No Sssweat To make my life you advise me to use "Views data export" or "Views DataSource" ?

Comment: @Mathieu I've never used either, so I don't really know.

Comment: @No Sssweat I managed to run your code with the "Views Data Export" module, it displays good tags but no content between its tag. I've updated the capture of the question.

Comment: @Mathieu how did you do it? what steps did you do?

Comment: @No Sssweat I followed devotees onstruction http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198877/html-tags-removed-during-views-rewriting and I replaced the module: "Views DataSource" by "Views data export". As against it lack the data between the two tags.

Comment: `I followed devotees` who is devotees? couldn't find any user name called "devotees"

Comment: excuse me I meant
 "I followed your instruction"

Comment: What an interesting "discussion" ... Sorry I ask, but what exactly is the question about that image in an XML file? I seem to understand it has to do with "*... customize the image field of my view ...*", right? Would you be interested in another module recommendation where (a) you create a tabular display with rows and columns that you want and then (b) save (export) that as JSON, XML, CSV, (or some other formats). If that's what the goal is, then I'd be happy to post an answer to do so.